# How do I redirect calls to ole32.dll to my own proxy DLL?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, tstcon32

I'm trying to detect all calls to [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615(v=vs.85).aspx) in some process I'm starting (ideally, I'm able to detect calls in child processes as well).

To achieve this, using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7, I create a proxy DLL which forwards all but one call in the standard `ole32.dll` library as described in various articles, e.g. 
[Intercepted: Windows Hacking via DLL Redirection](http://www.ethicalhacker.net/content/view/207/24/). The resulting DLL looks fine, but I just can't make existing programs (I'm using the standard [ActiveX Control Test Container (tstcon32.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241446(v=vs.80).aspx) as a test application) pick up my proxy DLL. No matter what I do, the programs always seem to pick up `C:\Windows\SysWow64\ole32.dll` according to [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). I tried a few things so far:

1. Prepend the directory which contains my proxy DLL to the `PATH` and then invoke the program; didn't seem to have any effect.
2. Copy my proxy DLL into the same directory as the invoked program; no luck.
3. Create a `.local` file in the same directory as the invoked program as described in the [Dynamic-Link Library Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682600) article and put my proxy DLL into the same directory - didn't work either. But then, I read that this stopped working on more recent Windows versions. Additionally, `ole32.dll` is a "known DLL" according to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs` registry setting, so `.local`-based redirection is probably not going to work anyway.
4. Use manifest-based redirection as described e.g. in the [DLL redirection using manifests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100973/dll-redirection-using-manifests) question, but that didn't seem to have any effect either. However, this approach seems to be non-trivial, so chances are I did something wrong.

Does anybody have experience with redirecting calls to standard DLLs such as `ole32.dll` using a stub DLL? How did you force the applications to pick up your stub DLL?

Comment: I've had pleasant experiences with [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/), which shouldn't have the problems you're describing.

Comment: @ildjarn: Yes, I use something like that in other places. My hope is that a redirection DLL (hopefully) works for sub processes of the given program as well.

Comment: Perhaps tangentially of interest: http://www.darknet.org.uk/2010/08/windows-binary-planting-dll-preloadinghijacking-bug/

Comment: Stubbing a system library like OLE32 may cause problems, unless you dynamically load (explicitly from the system directory) the original and forward all calls. Using a different DLL that is easier to inject will help; however, *do not use Detours*. It's extremely buggy and doesn't handle recursion or thread-safety. Other libraries, such as EasyHook, will serve much better if you chose to inject+detour.

Answer (score 5):

I realise this is a little late by about 6 months, but I was trying the same thing and have some additional notes:

1. You can take ownership of and remove `ole32.dll` from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\KnownDLLs`. This allows you to get around the fact Windows has locked these keys.
2. Creating a key `SafeDllSearch` with the value `0` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager` is [supposed to alter the search path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Having applied both these techniques and rebooting, hooking still did not work. I went one further, booted up a VM with one of our rescue CDs (a Windows PE based environment) and overwrote the one in `system32`. Windows does not boot as a result - no symbol errors, but I never get as far as `LogonUI.exe`. It is possible my hooked functions are broken, so this may be the cause.

Anyway, that produced an actual, tangible hook effect - albeit one that screams "broken"!. Unfortunately it appears highly difficult to debug, and I may be resorting to the other method of hooking - namely [IAT patching](http://www.autosectools.com/IAT-Hooking-Revisited.pdf).

**Edit** another experiment I performed was to explicitly load the Dll myself into the target process' address space. A snippet of code that does this looks like this:

```
wchar_t* TargetPath = argv[1];
wchar_t DllPath[] = L"N:\\experiments\\ole32.dll";
STARTUPINFOW si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
memset(&si, 0, sizeof(STARTUPINFOW));
memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

// create process suspended
BOOL bResult = CreateProcess(NULL, TargetPath, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 
    CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);

// write DLL name to remote process
void* RemoteAddr = VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, NULL, sizeof(DllPath)+1, 
    MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READONLY);
WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, RemoteAddr, DllPath, sizeof(DllPath), &BytesWritten);

// get handle to LoadLibraryW
PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE pfLoadLibrary = (PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE) 
    GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(L"kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryW");

// create remote thread calling LoadLibraryW
HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(pi.hProcess, NULL, 
    0, pfLoadLibrary, RemoteAddr, 0, NULL);

// start remote process
ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
```

Error handling removed for brevity.

Basically, the objective was to force load my `ole32.dll` into the target's address space before it had chance to load `ole32.dll` from system32. In my case, `ole32.dll` was being loaded later on in the application's load routine, so this in theory should have worked. In practice, it did not. I am not sure why.

**Update** My original code failed because the DLL had unresolved symbol warnings at runtime. <strike>This technique does work</strike> So apparently, it loads both my `ole32.dll` AND the one from system32. To ensure the library was loading successfully, I added a `LoadLibrary(DllPath)` call to the code above.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply after six months (and your findings are certainly interesting!).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [winapioverride](http://jacquelin.potier.free.fr/winapioverride32/) can help you. It can log all win api calls without programming anything. It therefore injects dlls to the process that do the logging. If I recall it correctly it is also possible to inject own custom dlls - even before the process actually executes any code. The documentation has some information about spying com objects.