# Altering DLL search path for static linked DLL

Tags: c++, dll, linker, redirect, manifest

I've searched for any hints how I can do this, but all I found was how to redirect a SxS DLL to the local application folder.
Here is what I want to accomplish:
The (C++) Application.exe is linked to a DLL, Plugin.DLL (dependant project). This DLL is not placed inside the application directory, but in a subfolder called "plugins". As the DLL is statically linked, the application would try to load it from the application folder.

Is there any way how I can change the search path for this particular DLL? Either through manifests or VS2008 linker configurations?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My first thought is, if you are statically linking a dll, it isnt a plugin. Just put the dll in the EXE folder and be done with it. That is the deployment configuration supported by windows for statically loaded DLLs.

That said, there are ways to achieve what you want. But they are mostly stupid, or complicated for no good reason: Your options are:

- Don't statically link. Use LoadLibrary("plugins/Plugin.dll") & GetProcAddress to access plugin content.
- Add "the path to your plugins folder" to the systems PATH environment variable.
- Use the delay load mechanism to delay accessing the plugins functionality, set a [custom helper function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09t6x5ds.aspx) that can load the dll(s) using a provided path.
- Turn the plugins folder into an assembly (by creating a .manifest file in it that lists the plugin.dll). Add "plugins" as a dependent assembly to your app. Now it will look in the plugins folder.
- Split your application into a stub exe and a dynamically loaded part. In the stub exe call SetDllDirectory to point to the plugin folder, then call LoadLibrary passing the full path to "appstub.dll".

---

To turn a folder, with one or more dll's into an "assembly", simply add a file to the folder with the folders name.manifest.

So, plugins.manifest :-

```
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="Plugins" version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="x86" />
  <file name="Plugin.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

It is a VERY good idea to ensure that the folder and the dll's name is different as if the dll name is the assembly name windows starts looking at its embedded manifest file for information about the assembly.

Assuming you are using Visual Studio 7 or later, the following directive added to a .c/.cpp or .h file in the project will then make your application attempt to load dlls from the assembly rather than just the local directory:

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"name='Plugins' "\
                        "processorArchitecture='*' version='1.0.0.0' "\
                        "type='win32'\"")
```

Comment: Thanks - I've gone with the GetProcAddress approach now cause I couldn't figure out how the manifest has to look like to make the "fake assembly" approach work. Fortunately, this works well with the overall architecture.

Comment: You don't need `SetDllDirectory` for delay loading; there's a `__pfnDliNotifyHook2` hook so you can call `LoadLibrary(".\\plugins\\PluginX.dll")` directly. The `%PATH%` idea is a bit fragile as that's rather low on the list of locations to check.

Comment: thanks. I've never personally used delay loading so I just assumed that SetDllDirectory would be the way to tune it.

Comment: I disagree in part.  I support an application that provides an OCX for a 3rd party application.  We have no control of the 3rd party application.  We could install the OCX into the same folder as the EXE.  However, the 3rd party erases this folder and recreates it when their application is upgraded.  This means our OCX needs to be reinstalled.  This is very problematic for the user base.   We deploy our OCX to a unique folder and add the path to the PATH environment variable.  This is complicated, but it is not stupid.

Answer (score 11):

Expanding and [detailing Chris' proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3832428/321013) of an "assembly" subdirectory:

---

Side note: Chris also has two excellent write ups of more details:

- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2103032/321013) to  [DLL redirection using manifests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100973/dll-redirection-using-manifests)
- [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1973332/321013) to [A way to load DLL from central repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969360/a-way-to-load-dll-from-central-repository)

  This on also explains how you can leverage `probing privatePath` in the application config files to put the DLLs outside of a subfolder.

---

## MS docs

This is actually called a ["Private Assembly"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff951638%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and MS docs explain it this way:

> Private assemblies are installed in a folder of the application's
>   directory structure. Typically, this is the folder containing the
>   application's executable file. Private assemblies **may be deployed** in
>   the same folder as the application, **in a folder with the same name as
>   the assembly**, or in a language specific subfolder with the same name
>   as the assembly.
>
> For example (...)
>
> `Appdir\Microsoft.Tools.Pop\Microsoft.Tools.Pop.MANIFEST` : The manifest is deployed as a separate file in a subfolder having the assembly's name.
>
> (...)
>
> Private assemblies can be installed by any installation method that can copy the assembly's file into this folder, such as the `xcopy` command.

## The example

You got you're trusty old executable in you program folder `C:\Test\Program\app.exe` and you want to -- [at Load-Time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686923%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) -- load your DLL file from the `Plugins` subfolder, i.e. `C:\Test\Program\plugins\tool1.dll` *without* messing with `PATH`or any other stuff.

You need to:

- Compile app.exe with:

  ```
  #pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"name='Plugins' version='1.0.0.0' type='win32'\"")
  // name, type and version seems to be the minimum info to get away with
  ```

  **Note:** Compiling/Linking this in, instead of using an external manifest (`app.exe.manifest`) is required on my test system, I didn't find out why yet. (*a)

  What also *works* however is embedding/merging the manifest file listed below into the executable with the `mt`tool, instead of with the linker pragma. (`Configuration > Manifest Tool > Additional Manifest Files`)
- put tool1.dll intro the `plugins` subfolder
- add a plugins.manifest file *into* the plugins subfolder, i.e. `C:\Test\Program\plugins\plugins.manifest` and that one looks like this:

plugins.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <assemblyIdentity
                            type="win32"
                            name="Plugins"
                            version="1.0.0.0"
            />
    <file name="tool1.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

That's it. Starting app.exe will automatically find the dll in the subfolder at Load-Time.

---

(*a) : Merging this manifest file works, but you can't use that as the sole external manifest file, and I suspect it's because it's missing all the other manifest info the build system already places into your executable!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <!-- Note: type: The value must be win32 and all in lower case. Required. --> 
            <!-- Note: version: The value must be win32 and all in lower case. Required. --> 
            <assemblyIdentity
                                    type="win32"
                                    name="plugins"
                                    version="1.0.0.0"
            />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Comment: The numpy wiki @ https://github.com/numpy/numpy/wiki/windows-dll-notes alsohas a nice write up of this

Comment: The external manifest file is only used I think if there is no embedded manifest file. The VS compiler now embeds manifests by default so runtime loading of manifests is only possible if you remove that first.

Comment: I confirm the approach with extra manifest works for executables built with VS2017.