# How do I specify the .DLL search path for an MFC .EXE?

Tags: c++, mfc, manifest

How do I specify the .DLL search path for an MFC .EXE?  It would need to be a relative path, not absolute.  Is this what the Manifest File is for?

Comment: Oh, I do NOT want my install to tweak the PATH environment variable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Altering DLL search path for static linked DLL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832290/altering-dll-search-path-for-static-linked-dll)

Comment: Implicit or explicitly loaded DLLs?  Big difference.  Make the relative path .\, all problems solved.

Comment: Anybody have experience with "App Paths" registry entry?

Comment: BTW, the possible duplicate "Altering DLL search path for static linked DLL" is asking the question about a DLL-centric search path (and I quote) "Is there any way how I can change the search path for this particular DLL?".  I want to change the search path for ANY/ALL .DLLs implicitly linked to my MFC .EXE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**THERE IS NO ANSWER**

In order for my "answer rate" to be acceptable to those out there who only look at numbers (not the actual answers), I'm answering my own long-outstanding-unanswered questions as "there is no answer" (if one shows up, I'll definitely choose their answer as THE answer).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SetDllDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686203%28VS.85%29.aspx)().

Comment: Sorry, I need this for implicitly loaded DLLs, so I don't believe SetDllDirectory can work.