# Linking dlls from subfolder - Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I built my project and in configuration folders (ie. release) I have .exe files. I copied (manually) all .dll there but it looks messy. Now I want to move that dlls to subfolder, but in that case app can't find dlls. 
Is there any way to set directory in Visual Studio 2010 to look for dll in subfolder?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no such option in Visual Studio, because it's not Visual Studio that loads these DLL's. C++ is a compiled language; Visual Studio produces executables and DLL's for Windows to run. And Windows doesn't look at Visual Studio settings when running executables - your typical user probably doesn't even have Visual Studio installed!

As for Windows checking subdirectories - it's [possible with manifests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832290/altering-dll-search-path-for-static-linked-dll) but not easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Using runtime dynamic linking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686944(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I already know this solution. I search something to set in Visual Studio (if there is such possibility) not using dynamic linking.