# MSVC embedded application assembly manifest

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, manifest

I've followed Microsoft's docs about manifests and wanted to use one in my application https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-embed-a-manifest-inside-a-c-cpp-application?view=msvc-170

I'm using CMake as my build system for a graphics engine,
I have a target `A` linking my `assembly manifest`, let's call it `test.manifest`(and a dynamic library `Test_debug`) specified in sources list when creating this target (CMake allows to handle any `*.manifest` files this way)

```
add_executable(A main.cpp <path>/test.manifest)
```

the `test.manifest` looks following

```xml
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0">
  <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="MyCompany.Windows.Test" version="1.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="0000000000000000" />
  <file name="Test_debug.dll"/>
</assembly>
```

my target `A` needs to load the `Test_debug.dll` and this library should be located given assembly directory thanks to application assembly manifest

the `Test_debug.dll` is located at path `x/y/z/Test_debug.dll`, the `assembly manifest` is located at `x/y/z/test.manifest/test.manifest`

my target `A` that links imported library `Test_debug.lib` therefore needs `Test_debug.dll` has following pragma in it's source cpp code

```cpp
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"name='MyCompany.Windows.Test' "\
                        "version='1.0.0.0' "\
                        "type='Win32'\"")
```

but for some reason when I try to launch target `A` executable I get this message from Event Viewer

`Activation context generation failed for "an_absolute_path\bin\A.exe". Dependent Assembly MyCompany.Windows.Test,type="Win32",version="1.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.`

and this when it tries to execute `A` exe

`The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail`

if I get this correctly having my assembly manifest located close to `Test_debug.dll` should make this directory an assembly and make my `Test_debug.dll` findable, but I'm not sure and seems like I'm missing something

Comment: Docs say "type" value must be all lower case.

Comment: eh according to docs I think I should have installed my `assembly` with my DLL resource under the `%WINDIR%\WinSxS\manifest\<somewhere_here>` via merge modules like `.msi` to make sure this assembly is `shared assembly` therefore visible when querying my assembly in my application, but for my purposes it's bad idea because I have more than 60 applications that need this one DLL, I don't want to have copies of DLL, BUT I don't want to install any assembly in system paths either so I rather stay with `LoadLibrary` probably

Comment: Oh! I resolved my issues with this helpful comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/1973332/13906958 following those instructions will let you avoid PATH env variable and go with private assemblies